# C# Cntrl dot namespace resolving issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm unsure how else to put it.

I normally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to resolve a namespace and it helps my productivity massively.

Until recently I'd use the shortcut to add a using reference, but since yesterday the default behaviour is to reference inline e.g

```
using System.IO; // what I'd want when I use the shortcut

MyMethod(System.IO.DirectoryInfo di) // what I'm getting
```

I've no idea what I've changed and would be grateful for any insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened after updating to the latest VS2017 release.
The solution was to disable F# in extensions and updates :S

Fixed (oddly)!